# Show/hide div when use select form - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found such a script on the forum, but I have a question how to make the first div open by default.

Link to jffiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lessiuu/mtq7fbge/3/.

Unfortunately, my skills do not allow me to modify the script, so I will be very grateful for any help from the forums. Thanks for all answers!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .red{ background: #ff0000; }
        .green{ background: #228B22; }
        .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
                var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
                if(optionValue){
                    $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                    $("." + optionValue).show();
                } else{
                    $(".box").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <select>
                <option>Choose Color</option>
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
        <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
        <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just remove `<option>Choose Color</option>`.

Comment: or add `selected` attribute to the option you want to be selected by default: `<option value="red" selected>Red</option>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u want.

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red" selected>Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the fastest and maybe one of the easiest way to fix this is to remove the "Choose Color" option, so you will end up with

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Or just assigne the `value="red"` to your `Choose Color` option and delete the red option, like this

```
<div>
    <select>
        <option value="red">Choose Color</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

or assigne a `selected` attribute to your red div

```
<select>
        <option>Choose Color</option>
        <option value="red" selected>Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```